# cant solve the mouseout for IOS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, mouseout

first of all i'm no js expert,and all my know how,is from web and mainly from here.
I code a js (jquery) which is based on aion MMORPG and shows tooltips related to the item-id or what else can be found ingame. I came across several hurdles while creating this,and solved one problem after another.right or wrong, my knowledge can not decide this.but all the code works.
What I can not solve is a mouseout if you touch the  on IOS devices.
android devices seems to work great,but i'am unable to solve it for IOS.
the tooltip disapears on -touch but the link has still a hovered state on IOS.
first touch opens tooltip second touch the href link.
i want the second touch on body should reset the href link an next touch should open tooltip again.
and maybe a js guru can give me some hints how i can code this a little smaller.
i made this
[(DEMO)](http://jsfiddle.net/oao3006j/20/)

```
$(document).on('touchstart', function() {
    detectTap = true;
});
$(document).on('touchmove', function() {
    detectTap = false;
});
$(document).on('click touchend', function(event) {
    if (event.type == "click") detectTap = true;
    if (detectTap) {
        TT_Item_wegmachs();

    }
});
```

and hope for any solution.thx

Answer (score 0):

i found temp solution that helped me,to get IOS mobiles loose hovered on focused element state on body tab.

on "touchstart" i add class to "body" with "cursor:pointer;".
now if i tab on body elswhere,the hovered element on IOS mobiles becomes a "mouseout".
and after that i remove class from "body".

Nevertheless I am happy about better answers